# returning functions from a method in python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have tried looking into the documentation and google search , but I am unable to find out the significance of the [clazz] at the end of method. Could someone help me understand the meaning of the [clazz] at the end of the method? Thanks.

```
def get_context_setter(context, clazz):
        return {
            int: context.setFieldToInt,
            datetime: context.setFieldToDatetime
        }[clazz]
```

setFieldToInt and setFieldToDatetime are methods inside context class.

Comment: It looks like it's building a dictionary and then immediately accessing the key passed in as the `clazz` argument.

Comment: So you pass it the `int` class or the `datetime` class and it returns a constructor for that context and class

Comment: sorry, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns one of two things. It returns either `context.setFieldToInt` or `context.setFieldToDatetime`. It does so by using a dictionary as what would be a `switch` statement in other programming languages.

It checks whether `clazz` is a reference to the class `int` or a reference to the class `datetime`, and then returns the appropriate method.

It's identical to this code:

```
def get_context_setter(context, clazz):
    lookup_table = {int: context.setFieldToInt,
                    datetime: context.setFieldToDatetime
                   }
    context_function = lookup_table[clazz] # figure out which to return
    return context_function
```

Using a dict instead of a `switch` statement is pretty popular, see [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/) .

Answer (score 0):

More briefly. 
The code presented is expecting the class of some object as a parameter poorly named as clazz. 
It's then using that class as a dictionary key. 
They're essentially trying to accept two different types and call a method on the object type.

class is a keyword in Python. 
The author of the code you show chose to use a strange spelling instead of a longer snake_case parameter name like obj_class.
The parameters really should have been named obj, obj_class
Or
instance, instance_class

Even better, the class really need not be a separate parameter.